# problem in retrieving records based on multiple form values from database in ASP?

Tags: oracle, asp-classic

I am not able to retrieve records from Oracle based on multiple inputs.

Here is my code:

Search.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>SearchMDFnode</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head> 

<body bgcolor="#99CCFF">

<p align="center"><font color="#9966CC" size="5" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif"><strong>Records</strong></font></p>
  <style>
    A:link {text-decoration: none;color: blue;}
    A:visited {text-decoration: none;}
    A:hover {text-decoration:underline; color: red;}
</style>
  <script>
    function updateDate(fname){
        var instDate = showModalDialog('upd_date.html','Select Date','dialogHeight:375px;dialogWidth:287px;status:no;resizable:no;help:no;');
        if (instDate == -1 || instDate == null){        
            alert("You did not select any date.")
            fname.focus()
        } else {
            fname.value = instDate
        }
    }
    function findNull(frm,tname,optnull,optorder){
        var nfname = optnull.value
        var ofname = optorder.value
        frm.action = "MDFnodeDisplayTable.asp?opt=" + tname + "&nfield=" + nfname + "&order=" + ofname
        frm.submit()
    }

</script>      

  <form name="SearchMDFnode" action="Display.asp?opt=MDFnode" method="post">
    <table width="68%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
    <table width="94%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
        <td width="19%">CCP_CODE</td>
        <td width="22%"><strong>
          <select name="CCP_CODE" id="select4" title="BLOCK_HOUSE">
            <option></option>
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>AR</option>
            <option>BD</option>
            <option>BP</option>
            <option>CG</option>
            <option>CT</option>
            <option>CY</option>
            <option>ES</option>
            <option>GL</option>
            <option>HG</option>
            <option>JE</option>
            <option>JR</option>
            <option>JW</option>
            <option>KT</option>
            <option>NT</option>
            <option>OC</option>
            <option>PL</option>
            <option>QT</option>
            <option>TB</option>
            <option>TP</option>
            <option>TS</option>
          </select>
        </strong></td>
        <td width="19%">NODE_SITE_ID</td>
        <td width="40%"><strong>
          <input name="NODE_SITE_ID" type="text" id="NODE_SITE_ID" size="10" maxlength="10" title="NODE_SITE_ID(max 7 digits)">
        </strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>STREET_NAME</td>
        <td><strong>
          <input name="STREET_NAME" type="text" id="STREET_NAME" size="30" maxlength="30" title="STREET_NAME(max 30 digits)">
        </strong></td>
        <td>BUILDING_NAME</td>
        <td><strong>
          <input name="BUILDING_NAME" type="text" id="BUILDING_NAME" size="25" maxlength="25" title="BUILDING_NAME(max 7 digits)">
        </strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="38">BLOCK_HOUSE</td>
        <td><strong>
          <select name="BLOCK_HOUSE" id="select3" title="BLOCK_HOUSE">
            <option></option>
            <option>BLOCK</option>
            <option>HOUSE</option>
          </select>
        </strong></td>
        <td>BLOCK_DESC_NO</td>
        <td><strong>
          <input name="BLOCK_DESC_NO" type="text" id="BLOCK_DESC_NO" size="6" maxlength="6" title="BLOCK_DESC_NO(max 6 digits)">
        </strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>REMARK</td>
        <td><strong>
          <input name="REMARK" type="text" id="REMARK" size="50" maxlength="50" title="REMARK(max 50 char)">
        </strong></td>
        <td>EQ_RM</td>
        <td><strong>
          <input name="EQ_RM" type="text" id="EQ_RM" size="3" maxlength="3" title="EQ_RM(max 6 digits)">
        </strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TYPE</td>
        <td><strong>
          <select name="EQ_TY" id="select" title="EQ_TY">
            <option>CE</option>
            <option></option>
          </select>
        </strong></td>
        <td>CE_TY</td>
        <td><strong>
          <input name="CE_TY" type="text" id="CE_TY" size="10" maxlength="10" title="CE_TY(max 6 digits)">
        </strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="32">STATUS</td>
        <td><strong>
          <select name="STATUS" id="select2" title="EQ_TY">
            <option></option>
            <option>-</option>
            <option>Site Survey</option>
            <option>Survey Done</option>
            <option>Document Sent</option>
            <option>Equipment Installed</option>
            <option>Commissioned</option>
            <option>Cancelled</option>
          </select>
        </strong></td>
        <td>NO</td>
        <td><strong>
          <input name="NO" type="text" id="NO" size="3" maxlength="3" title="NO (max 7 digits)">
          <input name="UNIT_DESC_NO" type="text" id="UNIT_DESC_NO" size="2" maxlength="2" title="UNIT_DESC_NO (max 1 digits)">
          <input name="NO_ME_CCTS" type="text" id="NO_ME_CCTS" size="2" maxlength="2" title="NO_ME_CCTS (max 2 digits)">
          <input name="Rack" type="text" id="Rack" size="2" maxlength="2" title="Rack (max 1 digits)">
          <input name="INSTALL_BY" type="text" id="INSTALL_BY" size="2" maxlength="2" title="INSTALL_BY (max 2 digits)">
        </strong></td>
      </tr>
  <td height="32"><font color="#000000" size="3" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif">Order By</font></td>
      <td colspan="5"><select name="oMDFnode">
          <option value="STATUS">STATUS</option>
          <option value="NO">NO</option>
          <option value="CCP_CODE">CCP_CODE</option>
          <option value="CCP_CODE">NODE_SITE_ID</option>
        </select>
          <select name="orMDFnode" id="orMDFnode">
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
            <option value="STATUS">STATUS</option>
            <option value="CCP_CODE">CCP_CODE</option>
            <option value="CCP_CODE">NODE_SITE_ID</option>
          </select>
          <select name="ordMDFnode" id="ordMDFnode">
            <option value="CCP_CODE">NODE_SITE_ID</option>
            <option value="CCP_CODE">NO</option>
            <option value="CCP_CODE">STATUS</option>
            <option value="CCP_CODE">CCP_CODE</option>
        </select></td>
  </tr>
    </table>
    <p align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">
    </p>
  </form>
  <form name="commNull" method="post">
      <tr> 
        <td height="56" colspan="4"><div align="center">
          </div></td>
    </tr>
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Display.asp

```
<%  option explicit %>
<!-- METADATA TYPE = "typelib" File = "c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" -->
  <%
    dim strTitle
    dim strF, fname, ropt, j, i, sno, ropt1
    dim objRS, strQuery, strConn, strSort,strQuery1 
    dim strHref
    dim nodesiteid
    'dim eq_ty

   'ropt1 = request("opt1")  
   ropt = request("opt")
   'eq_ty = request("EQ_TY")
   nodesiteid = request("NODE_SITE_ID")
   strQuery1 = request("NODE_SITE_ID")

    Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    strConn = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=hr;User ID=hr;Data Source=xe;Persist Security Info=True"
    strSort = ""

     strF = "CCP_CODE, NODE_SITE_ID, STREET_NAME, BLOCK_HOUSE, BLOCK_DESC_NO, UNIT_DESC_NO, BUILDING_NAME, EQ_RM, EQ_TY, CE_TY , Rack, INSTALL_BY, STATUS, NO, RFS_DATE, REMARK, NO_ME_CCTS, NO_ME_CCTS"        'these were fields in sql table as well as input name in form
     fname= split(strF,",",-1,vbtextcompare)                'split the above string to individual field         

        if trim(strQuery1) ="" then 
            strQuery = "select rowid,CCP_CODE, NODE_SITE_ID, STREET_NAME, BLOCK_HOUSE, BLOCK_DESC_NO, UNIT_DESC_NO, BUILDING_NAME, EQ_RM, EQ_TY, CE_TY , Rack, INSTALL_BY, STATUS, NO, RFS_DATE, REMARK, NO_ME_CCTS from MDF_NODE where CCP_CODE = CCP_CODE"

        else
                strQuery = "select rowid,CCP_CODE, NODE_SITE_ID, STREET_NAME, BLOCK_HOUSE, BLOCK_DESC_NO, UNIT_DESC_NO, BUILDING_NAME, EQ_RM, EQ_TY, CE_TY , Rack, INSTALL_BY, STATUS, NO, RFS_DATE, REMARK, NO_ME_CCTS from MDF_NODE where CCP_CODE = CCP_CODE and NODE_SITE_ID="
                strQuery = strQuery & "'" & strQuery1 & "'"
        end if

    strSort  =  " order by " & request("oMDFnode") & "," & request("orMDFnode")  & "," & request("ordMDFnode")
    strTitle = "Summary of Carrier Ethernet Node"

    if trim(request("nfield"))= "" then
        j=0
         for i= 0 to ubound(fname)
           if request(fname(i)) <> "" then                  'process if user input value in field
             if j=0 then 
             strQuery = strQuery & " and " & fname(i)  &  " like '" & request(fname(i)) & "' "   '1st field shd start with where clause
             j = j + 1

         else 
             strQuery = strQuery & " and " & fname(i) & " like '" & request(fname(i)) & "' "    'rest shd start with and clause
               j = j + 1

               end if
             end if
         next
         strQuery = strQuery & strSort
    else
        strQuery = strQuery & " where " & trim(request("nfield")) & " is null order by " & trim(request("order"))
    end if

     objRS.Open strQuery, strConn,adOpenStatic,adLockOptimistic,adCmdText           'open recordset query oracle database
        if objRS.eof then                                                           
            objRS.close
            set objRS = nothing
            response.write "<script>alert('No Rows Selected')</script>"                 'if eof mean NO data return
            response.write "<script>history.back()</script>"
        else
%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>SdhTermDisplayTable2</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#99CCFF"><div align="center">
<p align="left"><strong> 
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p> 

  </p>
  </strong> 
  <table width=945  align="center">
    <tr class="nonPrint" height=30> 

      <td width="646" nowrap style="vertical-align:middle;font:bolder 12pt verdana;" > 
        <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <font size="4" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font size="4" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;Records/font></strong></td>

  </table>
  <strong>
  <% 
    if trim(request("nfield"))= "" then
        j=0
         for i= 0 to ubound(fname)
           if request(fname(i)) <> "" then                  'process if user input value in field
             if j=0 then 
             strQuery = strQuery & " where " & fname(i)  &  " like '" & request(fname(i)) & "' "   '1st field shd start with where clause
             j = j + 1
         else 
             strQuery = strQuery & " and " & fname(i) & " like '" & request(fname(i)) & "' "    'rest shd start with and clause
               j = j + 1
               end if
             end if
         next
         strQuery = strQuery & strSort
    else
        strQuery = strQuery & " where " & trim(request("nfield")) & " is null order by " & trim(request("order"))
    end if
        if objRS.eof then                                                           
            objRS.close
            set objRS = nothing
            response.write "<script>alert('No Rows Selected')</script>"                 'if eof mean NO data return
            response.write "<script>history.back()</script>"
        else
            call drawHeader(ropt)
            objRS.movefirst
            sno = sno + 1
            do until objRS.eof
                call drawB(fname)
                sno = sno + 1
                objRS.movenext
            loop
            objRS.close
            set objRS = nothing
        end if

sub drawHeader(ropt)
     response.write "<table id='tbl' table border=1 bordercolor='black' bgcolor='LavenderBlush' cellpadding=1 cellspacing=0 align=center style='BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse;'>"
  select case ropt 
     case "MDFnode"
        response.write "<tr height=20><td><b>SNo</b></td>"
        response.write "<td style='font:bold 11pt;' width=50>Exch</b></td><td><b>Cabinet</b></td><td><b>Street Name</b></td><td><b>BLK/HSE</b></td><td><b>No</b></td><td><b>Unit</b></td><td><b>Building Name</b></td><td><b>Room</b></td><td><b>Type</b></td><td><b>Equipment Type</b></td><td><b>Rack</b></td><td><b>Inst By</b></td><td><b>Status</b></td><td><b>ID</b></td><td><b>RFS Date</b></td><td><b>Remark</b></td><td><b>No of ccts</b></td>" 
      end select
        response.write"</tr>"
      end sub

      response.write"</table>" 

sub drawbody(ropt)
   response.write "<tr>"
  select case ropt 
     case "MDFnode"
         for i= 0 to 10 
            response.write "<td>" & i & "</td>" 
         next
      end select
        response.write"</tr>"
end sub

sub drawB(ofname)
    response.write "<tr>"
        for i = 0 to ubound(ofname)
            if isnull(objRS(i)) then
                response.write "<td>&nbsp;</td>"  
            else
                if i = 0 then
                    strHref = "<a href='e_" & ropt & ".asp?tname=" & ropt & "&rowid=" & server.URLEncode(trim(objRS("rowid"))) & "'>" & sno & "</a>"
                    response.write "<td style='font:normal 12pt Arial;'>" & strHref & "</td>"  
                else
                    response.write "<td style='font:normal 12pt Arial;'>" & trim(objRS(i)) & "</td>"  
                end if
            end if 
        next
    response.write "</tr>"
end sub

end if
response.write"</table>"

%>
  </strong></p> </div>

<div align="center">
  <input type="button" value="Save as Excel" onClick="vbscript:xlsReport()">  
</div>
  </p> 
  </body>
  </html>
 <script language="VBScript">
dim r, c, colcnt,row
sub xlsReport()
    window.status = "Export to Excel ... Please Wait ..."
    dim rownow
    colcnt = tbl.cells.length / tbl.rows.length
    set xls = createobject("Excel.Application")
    xls.visible = true
    xls.workbooks.add
    xls.worksheets.add
    for c = 0 to colcnt - 1
        xls.cells(3,c+1).value = tbl.rows(0).cells(c).innerText     
    next
    row = 3
    for r = 1 to tbl.rows.length -1
        for c = 0 to colcnt - 1                 
            xls.cells(row+r,c+1).value = tbl.rows(r).cells(c).innerText     
        next
    next
    xls.cells(1,1).value = txtRpt.innerText
    set xls = nothing
    window.status = "Done"
end sub
</script>

</div>
```

I am getting records based on `CCP_Code` and `NODE_SITE_ID` values.

Now I want to retrieve values only based on `TYPE = 'CE'` but I am not able to do this.

When I didn't select anything by default the `TYPE` value is `'CE'`. Click submit and it gives me only type `CE` values.

When I give `CCp_code` with `TYPE = empty` then it should give me all the records based on `CCP_Code`.

When I select `CCP_CODE` and `NODE_SITE_ID` it should give me values based on both.

When I select `CCP_CODE`, `NODE_SITE_ID` and `TYPE='CE'` then it should give me values based on these values.

Comment: While code samples are good, entire web pages are bad. I don't quite understand what you are saying in your final paragraph but it appears that if you search on 2 terms, all is good. Attempting to search on 1 term fails. If that is the problem, your query isn't handling NULL values correctly.  Also, you have a userid and password in plain text there, probably not a best practice to publish those on the internet.

Comment: Yes, If I search by two inputs its working fine, but when I try to search with one or three values am not able to retrieve the records, do I need to write one more query???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Google "SQL injection" for a start.

```
strQuery = strQuery & "'" & strQuery1 & "'"
```

But as a start I'd log the contents of "strQuery" just before the objRS.Open
Once you can see the query text, it should be easy to say why rows were or were not returned.